# Enable gzip compression not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

I am trying to compress my website using "enable gzip compression", I found lots of code but none of the code works for me, please suggest what to do

Server and php version: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38

website URL: http://new.rginfotech.co.in/

Score on GTmertix : F(0)

Below is my .htaccess code

```
# Enable GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml 
text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>




# Expires Headers - 2678400s = 60 days
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
</ifmodule>


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


# Cache Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
# Cache specified files for 31 days
<filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
</filesmatch>
# Cache HTML files for a couple hours
<filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesmatch>
# Cache PDFs for a day
<filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesmatch>
# Cache Javascripts for 31 days
<filesmatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: where I can find this "Apache config file", is it in my hosting server ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you first enabled the `mod_deflate` Apache module? To do that you must first edit the Apache config file and make sure the corresponding `LoadModule` command is uncommented:

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
```

If not, then uncomment it.
Restart Apache server and you will begin to see output compression.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please tell me where I can find this "Apache config file", is it in my hosting server ?